# How to divide visibleMapRect into cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to divide visibleMapRect in to 9 cells (3x3). if I a cell has more than 2 annotations I will remove them and show at most 2 annotations. I am doing this for perf reasons since some of my users might have thousands of annotations spread around the world and as they zoom out , trying to show thousands of pins does not make sense and cause perf problems hence divide and conquer :) . I wrote below code , as I move map, I realized I am only seeing annotations count from the center not south east corner.  What is the correct way to do this ? How can I fix this ?

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{   
int xM;
int yM;
MKMapRect SE_rect;

xM=1;yM=1;
SE_rect= MKMapRectMake(  mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x + mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width/3 * xM , mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y + mapView.visibleMapRect.size.height/3 * yM, mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width/3, mapView.visibleMapRect.size.height/3);
NSLog(@"SE annotation count : %lu %d %d " ,(unsigned long)[mapView annotationsInMapRect:SE_rect].count,xM,yM );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code seems to be correct. I miss calculated the regions, 
xM = 0 , yM=0  is NW corner
xM = 2 , yM=2  is SE corner
xM = 1 , yM=1  is center